# Deleting the files using Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I just tried out a Camel route to move such files which are modified in the last 10 days from input directory to output directory and after the transfer of all the files from input directory are deleted as I set the option delete=true.

```java
Date tenDaysBack = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 10*8640000);
from("file:data/input?noop=true")
    .filter(header("CamelFileLastModified").isGreaterThan(tenDaysBack))
    .to("file:data/output");
```

This worked fine. But now what I want to do is keep the files that were modified in the last 10 days in the input directory only and delete the rest. How can we do it using Camel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use parameter `filterFile` option of File component instead of filter
>   EIP

To look for file older than 10 days, try `filterFile=${date:file:yyyyMMddHHmm} <= ${date:now-240h:yyyyMMddHHmm}`

- `${date:file:yyyyMMddHHmm}` - file last modified time (up to minutes level)
- `${date:now-240h:yyyyMMddHHmm}` - time of current minus 10 days (up to minutes level)

Reference: [Camel File Component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/file-component.html) [Camel File Language](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/languages/file-language.html)

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. So you mean to say that I should add filterFile=${date:file:yyyyMMddHHmm} <= ${date:now-10d:yyyyMMddHHmm} option in the from ,method , right? I tried this but it is not working I am getting some errors.

  from("file:data/input?filterFile=${date:file:yyyyMMddHHmm} <= ${date:now-10d:yyyyMMddHHmm}&delete=true")
                .log("Body is ${body} and headers are ${headers}");

Comment: it is showing error for now-10d. Can you help me out?

Comment: When I am using now-10d its not working , I tried using now-240h . Its working with that